# Weighted buttons in vertical linear layout cutting off text if button text line counts vary

Tags: android, android-view, clipping

TL;DR: Here's the gist of everything that I can think of that's relevant to the issue I'm facing: [[GIST LINK]](https://gist.github.com/prateem/ef455aed329fcb404a50d0503593f4f1)

And here's a picture of the problem

[image: Text cutting off problem: illustrated]

I'm trying to set up a number of buttons that will all grow to the same size as each other by equal weighting in a vertically oriented `LinearLayout` container.

The problem I'm facing surfaces when the text on these buttons cause a different number of lines per button.

Let's say `n` is the lowest line count for the buttons and `m` is the highest line count; any descenders in the text of buttons with line count `m` are cut off. Refer to the words `"qshowing my clipping problem"` in the linked screengrab, where all descenders are cut off.

How can I go about fixing this? The clipping gets much worse if I introduce `android:lineSpacingExtra` to the button style.

If it's relevant, my minimum API is set to 21

Comment: I am doing a similar thing in my code and have zero issues. What I'm doing is I'm scaling the text using .setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_MM, letterSize); The font face that I'm using is Times New Roman. Hope this helps.

Comment: you can use paddingBotton of button property

Comment: Both scaling text and modifying padding will solve the problem but they're not ideal solvers; the primary problem being that if I wasn't using weighted buttons and had their heights all set to `wrap_contents`, the buttons would render just fine with nothing being clipped or cut off - the line height is not ignored. For design reasons, however, it is ideal that the buttons share the same height and have the text size and paddings already existing in the example. Is there anything I can do to coax Linear Layout weighting to take line height into proper consideration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed this using RxJava to set the height programmatically to the correct maximum so that no clipping occurs. If there is a better solution I'll be glad to see it, but this is what is working for me for now:

```
class MyActivity {

    // ...

    private val compositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        setContentView(R.layout.my_activity)
        // ...

        val container: LinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.container)

        val numBtns = getNumBtnsToAdd()
        val btnList: MutableList<Button> = mutableListOf()
        val margin10 = dpToPx(10f).toInt()

        val countDown = CountDownLatch(numBtns)
        val desiredLp = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0).apply {
            gravity = Gravity.CENTER
            setMargins(margin10, margin10, margin10, margin10)
        }

        // Completable will be run once per subscriber and emit a success or error
        val layoutCompletable = Completable.fromAction {
            countDown.await()
            for (btn in btnList) btn.layoutParams = desiredLp
        }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())

        compositeDisposable.add(
            layoutCompletable.subscribe({
                Log.d("MyActivity", "Set LayoutParams on all buttons.")
            }, Throwable::printStackTrace)
        )

        for (i in 0 until numBtns) {
            val btn = Button(this, null, 0, R.style.button_style).apply {
                layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(desiredLp).apply { height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENTS }
                text = if (i == 0) "Button${i+1} with short text"
                              else "Button${i+1} with text that will span multiple lines showing my clipping problem"
                setOnClickListener { doSomething() }
            }

            val listener = object : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
                override fun onGlobalLayout() {
                    countDown.countDown()
                    val height = btn.height
                    if (height > desiredLp.height) desiredLp.height = height
                    btn.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
                }
            }
            btn.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(listener)
            btnList.add(btn)
            container.addView(btn)
        }

        // ...
    }

    override fun finish() {
        compositeDisposable.clear()
        super.finish()
    }

    // ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess, the main cause is buttons have fixed size. More preciously, you use `LinearLayout` to share available room between buttons via `weight` attribute. You can see the single line button height is same with 2-lines button height. So 2-lines buttons are forced to clip the text.

According your XML file you want enable the vertical scroll when there is no more room. In this case you don't need to use `weight` attribute. Just buttons under each other with margins.

Comment: Scrolling is fine, the goal is to ensure the buttons are the same height as one another. The weight was being used so that the LinearLayout knew to assign heights as even distribution of "remaining" space, but "remaining" space in this context is as much as it needs (since the container's height is wrap_contents). Thus the buttons, to my understanding, should all grow to the largest size of all of the buttons (including line height/requirements of descenders and ascenders). You're right that it's because the buttons have a fixed size, but that should have been set so no clipping happens.

Comment: If I'm right you would see my explanation after you added one more button. Just curiosity, could you do that?

Comment: I want the buttons to be the same height though. If I don't use weight (outside of the solution I posted above), the buttons won't resize vertically and the one-line button will be smaller than the 2-line buttons.